# Node.js - Socket.io - Express 3

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm a noob to Node.js and Express :( I'm having an issue with accessing the socket.io object in other modules. I have created a global variable to hold a socket object however as soon as that user closes the connection the connection isn't available anymore. Technically I guess the connection still lives on but I delete it for resource reasons.

**Notice below everytime a connection is made we assign that socket to the global variable which is accessible to all other modules.**

```
// App.js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); 
var sessionsConnections = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) 
{
     global.socket = socket;
     sessionsConnections[socket.id] = socket;
     .....
}

socket.on("disconnect", function() 
{
    delete sessionsConnections[socket.id];
});

// Match.js
     global.socket.emit('lobby:createMatch', data);
```

If the connection last assigned to the global closes Match.js will be screwed. At this point Match.js is the only module who will ever need that socket.io reference. Match.js has a bunch of exports for handling events, emitting the changes and rendering the view.

Are there any suggestions to how this is handled? Is it possible to instantiate an initial socket connection to live in App.js for the purpose of being a global reference?

Comment: Are you trying to make something that handle only one connection ?
Do you test the value of global.socket before emiting ?
What is the error you get ?

Comment: Users are creating and connecting to matches all the time. The thing is this design works but its not full proof. When I test and connect a socket, assign it the global, disconnect and kill the socket and then try emitting on the global.socket it hangs and I eventually get an error saying cant find socket or something.

Comment: Ok, I think you didn't get the fact that `socket` is not unique but different for every user. The lortabac's answer will help you ;)

Comment: Nice way to format a question! This is exactly what my problem is!

Answer (score 4):

The `socket` variable in `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {...})` is different for each connection.

Since in your code `global.socket` is always a reference to the socket relative to the last connected client, it is normal that if this client disconnects, this socket will die.

In any case, I don't see any reason to use a global variable. If you need to send a message to a specific client, you can use the `socket` variable inside the connection callback:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) 
{
  socket.emit('foo', 'bar');
}
```

If you need to access the sockets in another module, you can export the `sessionsConnections` object, and access the socket you need by its id:

```
//In app.js
exports.connections = sessionsConnections;

//In match.js
var app = require('./app.js');
app.connections[clientId].emit('foo', 'bar');
```

Of course, you need to keep track of the id's somewhere.

Comment: That's why I asked Charles if only one client could connect. I think he didn't understand the fact Sockets where unique per connection. Good answer ;)

Comment: I did know that each socket was unique per connection. What I was trying to do was alert other connected users that userA had disconnected. If userA was tied to global (because he was the last to connect) obviously the emit wouldn't work. Lortabac's solution would work if the clientID wasnt deleted. Remember the user disconnected and and their socket connection is no longer available to emit. I could access another clientID from the sessionsConnections object.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [express.io](http://express-io.org),

http://express-io.org/

```
npm install express.io
```

It works the same as express, except that it has socket.io integration built-in.  It also has basic routing, so that it is a little easier to deal with your issue.

Check out this simple example:

```
app = require('express.io')()
app.http().io()

app.io.route('some-event', function(req) {
    req.io.broadcast('announce', 'someone triggered some-event')
})

app.listen(7076)
```

You can also do routing with objects, which makes it more like a traditional controller:

```
app = require('express.io')()
app.http().io()

app.io.route('posts', {
    create: function(req) {
        // create a post
    },
    remove: function(req) {
        // remove a post
    }
})

app.listen(7076)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh yea, and sessions work automatically!  Just set them up as normal in express, and they will be rigged up to the io requests as well.